# Use whole page width for aligned formulas

Tags: spacing, equations, arrays, split

How can I automatically increase the distance between the columns to use the whole horizontal space that is accessible for equations (this might not necessarily be the whole page width)? Note, that I use the environments `equation` and `split` as I want to write formulas with alignments that get a single number. I can set the spacing manually, e.g. by `\quad`, however, replacing it with `\hfill` does not work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a&=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)\\
b&=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
\end{split}
\quad
\begin{split}
c&=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)\\
d&=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your equations. BTW, are you sure that equations had to be from left to right  page border? From showed images this is not evident.

Comment: Amsmath has `flalign` (and `flalign*`). Do they do what you want?

Comment: @Zarko Code extended. If the equations are longer than shown in the example then it makes sense to have as much space as possible.

Comment: well, meanwhile I provide an answer ... is suggested solution is close to what you after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing that actually your equation is not to be from page border to border but have a bit bigger distance between equations columns ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{align}
\begin{split}
    a & = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)    \\
    c & = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
\end{split}
    &   &
\begin{split}
    b & = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)\\
    d & = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
\end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
You can also use `flalign` as sugggest by @mickep in his comment:

```
% preamble
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{flalign}
\begin{split}
    a & = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)    \\
    c & = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
\end{split}
    &   &
\begin{split}
    b & = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)\\
    d & = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
\end{split}
    \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Comment: Align environment works better here than equation and Flalign does want the OP wants.

Comment: @Author, better to stick suggestion in addendum to my answer.